# Math needed to correctly positioning subviews dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, math, logic

It's been a long day and my brain doesn't seem to want to cooperate with me anymore...

I iterate through a for-loop for each view within an array of subviews. Each subview height is 100 px. When the array has 1 item in it, the y-value of the view needs to be set to 0. When the array has 2 items in it, the view at index 0 needs to have a y value of 100, and the item at index 1 needs to have a y value of 0. And so on:

```
1 item: 0 = 0
2 items: 0 = 100, 1 = 0
3 items: 0 = 200, 1 = 100, 2 = 0
4 items: 0 = 300, 1 = 200, 2 = 100, 3 = 0
```

I need to be able to dynamically handle this correctly based solely on the number of items in the array. Here is the code I have so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [subViews count]; i++) {
    NSView *v = (NSView *)[subViews objectAtIndex:i];
    [v setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(copy.view.frame.origin.x, i * 100)];//This gives me the opposite of what I want...
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n = [subViews count];
for (NSView *v in subViews) {
    n--;
    [v setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(copy.view.frame.origin.x, n * 100)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert this before the cycle:
`int subviewCount = [subViews count];`

And `[subViews objectAtIndex: (subviewCount - i - 1)]` instead of `[subViews objectAtIndex: i]`

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
y = 100 * ([subViews count] - 1 - i)
```

Also, FYI, try using `for` loops in the following format:

```
for(NSView *thisView in subViews)
{
    int i = [subViews indexOfObject:thisView]; //To get the "i position"
    //The rest of the code can be the same
}
```

The reason for this is because if subViews is empty, a `for(int i = 0; i < [subViews count]; i++)` loop will run at least once, and crash when you execute `NSView *v = (NSView *)[subViews objectAtIndex:i];`

The `for(NSView *thisView in subViews)` won't execute if subViews is empty.

Comment: Fast enumeration is no longer very fast if you have to search the array for each object. Better keep track of the index (see my answer).

Comment: You are correct; Though the reason I was suggesting it was to prevent an index out of bounds error. The line of code to get the value of i was because the asker uses i in his code.